# Room Database reverse migration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

I'm currently working on Application, and I'm interested in finding the most efficient and reliable approach to reverse migration of the database. I've done some research, but I would greatly appreciate the expertise of the community to help me determine the best steps and practices.

What are some best practices or recommended strategies for the same?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have tried it with some modification of the tables and entities but getting error like:

> A migration from 2 to 1 is necessary....

Note: I don't want to clear database records because it's initial version of the app is already in play store and contains valuable things in the same.

Answer (score 2):

As it says you need to provide a [Migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#manual)

The body of the function should make the necessary changes i.e. reverse the changes made when migrating from 1 to 2.

With regard to best practice. TEST, TEST and TEST again (which implies always having the data backed or creatable so you can always test).

> I don't want to clear database records because it's initial version of the app is already in play store and contains valuable things in the same.

You probably would not have to, but it depends upon what the migration from 1 to 2 did. You would also have to revert the changes to the code accordingly. At a minimum the `@Entity` annotated classes that were changed as these are what determine the schema.

**Demo *long winded and just an example/introduction***

**Note** this obviously does not reflect your situation, it is a hypothetical situation. As such it covers a limited scope.

The demonstration covers a scenario where in version 1 a single table **Table1** exists. **Table1** has 3 columns, table1Id, table1Col1 and table1Col2. The `@Entity` annotated class **Table1** being:-

```
@Entity
data class Table1(
    @PrimaryKey
    val table1Id: Long?=null,
    val table1Col1: String,
    val table1Col2: String,
    /* New column for version 2 commented out for version 1
        NOTE impossible to not lose data in this column if reverting to version 1
        that is unless a more complex migration is undertaken
        e.g. renaming table1 then creating new table1 and then loading it from original renamed table1
        renamed table could then be utilised in migration from 1 to 2 if done again
     */
    //@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")
    //val table1Col3: Long
)
```

- note the comments regarding what will be changed for Version 2

In addition to the changes for version 2 commented upon in the above, version 2 will also have a new table **table2** added (this to demonstrate that table2 and it's data can be kept (but not utilised)). The `@Entity` annotated **Table2** class being:-

```
/*
    New table for version 2
    NOTE again impossible to no lose the data if the table is dropped
 */
@Entity
data class Table2(
    @PrimaryKey
    val table2Id: Long?=null,
    val table2Col1: String,
    val table2Col2: String
)
```

- Whether or not **Table2** is included, as far as Room is concerned, will, for the demo, be controlled by the entities defined by the `@Database` annotation

  - i.e. the entities parameter is used by Room to determine the tables that the database is comprised off according to Room's perspective.

    - Room does not care if other components exist other than what it expects (as the demo will show).

So for version 1 and then version 2 the `@Database` annotation will be:-

1. `@Database(entities = [Table1::class/*,Table2::class*/], version = DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)`
2. `@Database(entities = [Table1::class,Table2::class], version = DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)` i.e. Table2 is no longer commented out, so Room EXPECTS Table2 to exist for Version 2

The actual `@Database` annotated class (using the annotations above for the respective version) used for the demo is:-

```
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity and convenience */
                    .addMigrations(Migration_1to2, Migration_2to1)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }

        val Migration_1to2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (table2Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, table2Col1 TEXT NOT NULL, table2Col2 TEXT NOT NULL)")
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN table1Col3 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
            }
        }
        val Migration_2to1 = object : Migration(2, 1) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                //database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN table1Col3") //<<<< NOT AVAILABLE FOR SOME versions of ANDROID

                /* AS such alternative to from column is to rename original, create new table and load data from the original */
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO original_table1")

                /* NOTE SQL COPIED FROM generated java class same name as the @Database annotated class suffixed with _Impl */
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table1` (`table1Id` INTEGER, `table1Col1` TEXT NOT NULL, `table1Col2` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`table1Id`))")
                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO table1 SELECT table1Id, table1Col1,table1Col2 FROM original_table1 WHERE 1")
                //database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_table1") /* not necessary but will free some storage, LEFT IN for demo */
            }
        }

        fun dumpDatabaseSchemaToLog() {
            if (instance != null) {
                val csr = instance!!.openHelper.writableDatabase.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- as can be seen both the normal 1 to 2 Migration and the reversal from 2 to 1 are included.
- the **dumpDatabaseSchemaToLog** has been included to allow the full schema to be displayed (showing components, if any exist, that Room  doesn't care about (e.g. Table2 existing at version 2 when reverting from version 2 to 1))

A single `@Dao` annotated interface **AllDAOs** is used for both versions. This does need tailoring for each version as Room checks the SQL at run time.

For version 1 this is :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(table1: Table1): Long
    /* ONLY ALLOWABLE FOR VERSION 2 - comment out both lines for version 1 */
    //@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    //fun insert(table2Id: Table2): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table1")
    fun getAllFromTable1(): List<Table1>
    /* ONLY ALLOWABLE FOR VERSION 2 - comment out both lines for for version 1*/
    //@Query("SELECT * FROM table2")
    //fun getAllFromTable2(): List<Table2>
}
```

- as can be seen for version 1 Table2 functions are commented out, for version 2 they will be included.

As can be seen above the database version and also the database name are specified via constants, these being:-

```
const val DATABASE_VERSION=1
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
```

- DATABASE_VERSION will be changed to reflect the version to be used.

In addition to the code for the database, something needs to be done so some activity code, this needing to be tailored according to the version.

This activity code also includes some functions that obtain data before Room actually opens the database.

- **doesDatabaseExist** does as it says, checks to see if the database actually exists, returning true if it does and false if it does not
- **getDatabaseVersionBeforeAccessingViaRoom** gets the version from the database BEFORE Room access the database, it will return:-

  - **0** if the database does not exist (or 0 if the version has been set to 0, which Room will not do).
  - **1** when the actual version stored in the database is 1, this may be different to the value as per DATABASE_VERSION (e.g. for migrating from 1 to 2 the DATABASE_VERSION will(should) be 2)
  - **2** when the actual version is 2 and again would differ from DATABASE_VERSION when reverting from 2 to 1.

In addition to the above *Pre-Room access* functions, there are two other functions:-

- **loadDataIfRequired** which will load data when either table is first created (the onCreate function of a callback would not suffice for Table2 as the database exists).

  - this function has to be modified to suit the version (due to the `@Dao` function availability)
- **logAllData** which will extract data from the tables, writing the results to the log.

  - again, this needs to be modified to suit the version being used.

For version 1 (prior to moving to version 2 in preparation for the reversion from 2 to 1) the activity code is:-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    var dbVersionBeforeRoomOpen : Int=0
    var dbAlreadyExists: Boolean = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        /* Pre Room access stuff*/
        dbAlreadyExists = doesDatabaseExist()
        dbVersionBeforeRoomOpen = getDatabaseVersionBeforeAccessingViaRoom()
        Log.d(TAG,"Version of database (before Room Access) is ${dbVersionBeforeRoomOpen} if 0 then database does not exist")

        /* Access database via Room aka force open (typically would not be used)*/
        db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        loadDataIfRequired()
        logAllData()

    }
    fun logAllData() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Database Existed when started = ${dbAlreadyExists} " +
                "Version before Room access = ${dbVersionBeforeRoomOpen} " +
                "Version after Room access = ${db.openHelper.writableDatabase.version}")
        /* First dump the schema */
        TheDatabase.dumpDatabaseSchemaToLog()

        /* Extract Data from Table1 - Applicable for both versions 1 and 2 (if code amended as per the comments )*/
        for (t1 in dao.getAllFromTable1()) {
            /*!!!!!!!!!! Version 1 - comment out if using version 2 and uncomment version 2 code below */
            val currentRow = "ID=${t1.table1Id} COL1=${t1.table1Col1} COL2=${t1.table1Col2}"
            /*!!!!!!!!!! Version 2 - comment out if using version 1 and uncooment version 1 code above */
            //val currentRow = "TABLE1 ROW ID=${t1.table1Id} COL1=${t1.table1Col1} COL2=${t1.table1Col2} COL3=${t1.table1Col3}"
            Log.d(TAG, currentRow)
        }
        /* Extract Data from Table 2 - Applicable ONLY for version 2 (uncomment for version 2) */
        /*
        for (t2 in dao.getAllFromTable2()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"TABLE2 ROW ID=${t2.table2Id} COL1=${t2.table2Col1} COL2=${t2.table2Col2}")
        }

         */
    }
    private fun doesDatabaseExist(): Boolean {
        return this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).exists()
    }

    private fun getDatabaseVersionBeforeAccessingViaRoom(): Int {
        var rv = 0 /* default version 0 aka database does not exist */
        if (doesDatabaseExist()) {
            try {
                val sqliteDB =
                    SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
                rv = sqliteDB.version
                sqliteDB.close()
            } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        return rv
    }

    fun loadDataIfRequired() {
        if (DATABASE_VERSION == 1 && !dbAlreadyExists) {
            for (i in 0..5) {
                dao.insert(Table1(table1Col1 = "T1C1_ROW${i}", table1Col2 = "T1C2_ROW${i}"))
                /* No need for version 2 code (at least for the demo, although will not load data if starting with V2) */
            }
        }
        if (DATABASE_VERSION == 2 && dbVersionBeforeRoomOpen==1) {
            for (i in 10..20 step 2) {
                /* For version 2 only comment out line below for version 1 */
                //dao.insert(Table2(table2Col1 = "T2C1_ROW${i}", table2Col2 = "T2C2_ROW${i}"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Stage 1 - Initial Version 1 from a fresh install** (code as above)

The log includes:-

```
2023-09-03 14:35:48.314 D/DBINFO: Version of database (before Room Access) is 0 if 0 then database does not exist
2023-09-03 14:35:48.432 D/DBINFO: Database Existed when started = false Version before Room access = 0 Version after Room access = 1
2023-09-03 14:35:48.433 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e2e29ad
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out: 0 {
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out: 1 {
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    name=Table1
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Table1
2023-09-03 14:35:48.434 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `Table1` (`table1Id` INTEGER, `table1Col1` TEXT NOT NULL, `table1Col2` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`table1Id`))
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out: 2 {
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out:    name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 14:35:48.435 I/System.out:    tbl_name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 14:35:48.436 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2023-09-03 14:35:48.436 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2023-09-03 14:35:48.436 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 14:35:48.436 I/System.out: <<<<<
2023-09-03 14:35:48.442 D/DBINFO: ID=1 COL1=T1C1_ROW0 COL2=T1C2_ROW0
2023-09-03 14:35:48.442 D/DBINFO: ID=2 COL1=T1C1_ROW1 COL2=T1C2_ROW1
2023-09-03 14:35:48.443 D/DBINFO: ID=3 COL1=T1C1_ROW2 COL2=T1C2_ROW2
2023-09-03 14:35:48.443 D/DBINFO: ID=4 COL1=T1C1_ROW3 COL2=T1C2_ROW3
2023-09-03 14:35:48.443 D/DBINFO: ID=5 COL1=T1C1_ROW4 COL2=T1C2_ROW4
2023-09-03 14:35:48.443 D/DBINFO: ID=6 COL1=T1C1_ROW5 COL2=T1C2_ROW5
```

- As can be seen the database did not exist (version 0) but Room sets it to version 1 (and creates Table1)
- android_metadata is an android specific table (contains the locale)
- room_master is a Room table (stores a hash of the schema)
- Table1 has been loaded with 6 rows (aka the `loadDataIfRequired` function has done it's job).

**Stage 2 - rerun the App** (as a check to see what is)

The log is all the same (still only 6 rows, i.e. `loadDataIfRequired` did nothing as wanted) with the exception of the first 2 lines:-

```
2023-09-03 14:44:55.139 D/DBINFO: Version of database (before Room Access) is 1 if 0 then database does not exist
2023-09-03 14:44:55.157 D/DBINFO: Database Existed when started = true Version before Room access = 1 Version after Room access = 1
```

- The database existed this time and the version was 1 and stayed as 1 when Room accessed it.

**Stage 3 - Migration from 1 to 2**

The following changes were made:-

1. `const val DATABASE_VERSION=2`
2. `@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "0")` and `val table1Col3: Long` i.e. **table1Col3** introduced (note if a column is NOT NULL then a default value is required due to how SQLite undertakes the ADD COLUMN)
3. In the **AllDAOS* interface the `insert` function for Table2 and the function `getAllFromTable2` and the respective annotations are uncommented.
4. the `@Database` annotation is changed to introduce Table2, so it is `@Database(entities = [Table1::class,Table2::class], version = DATABASE_VERSION, exportSchema = false)`
5. in the **logAllData** function of **MainActivity** the line `val currentRow = "ID=${t1.table1Id} COL1=${t1.table1Col1} COL2=${t1.table1Col2}"` is changed to `//val currentRow = "ID=${t1.table1Id} COL1=${t1.table1Col1} COL2=${t1.table1Col2}"`.
6. also the line `//val currentRow = "TABLE1 ROW ID=${t1.table1Id} COL1=${t1.table1Col1} COL2=${t1.table1Col2} COL3=${t1.table1Col3}"` is uncommented *(so that the data for the new column **table1Col3** is shown in the log)*.
7. also the comments around the for loop for extracting data from Table2 are removed (so data from that table is included in the log).
8. in the **loadDataIfRequired** function the line `//dao.insert(Table2(table2Col1 = "T2C1_ROW${i}", table2Col2 = "T2C2_ROW${i}"))` is uncommented, so data is added when the migration takes place. Additionally the line that inserts data into Table1 is commented out as a Table1 object expects 3 parameters instead of the 2. (if not commented out the compile will fail).

The App was rerun **NOT INSTALLED**

The log now shows:-

```
2023-09-03 15:08:13.063 D/DBINFO: Version of database (before Room Access) is 1 if 0 then database does not exist
2023-09-03 15:08:13.160 D/DBINFO: Database Existed when started = true Version before Room access = 1 Version after Room access = 2
2023-09-03 15:08:13.161 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e30b3a9
2023-09-03 15:08:13.162 I/System.out: 0 {
2023-09-03 15:08:13.162 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.162 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 15:08:13.162 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out: 1 {
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    name=Table1
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Table1
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `Table1` (`table1Id` INTEGER, `table1Col1` TEXT NOT NULL, `table1Col2` TEXT NOT NULL, table1Col3 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`table1Id`))
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out: 2 {
2023-09-03 15:08:13.163 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    tbl_name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out: 3 {
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    name=table2
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    tbl_name=table2
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE table2 (table2Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, table2Col1 TEXT NOT NULL, table2Col2 TEXT NOT NULL)
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:08:13.164 I/System.out: <<<<<
2023-09-03 15:08:13.169 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=1 COL1=T1C1_ROW0 COL2=T1C2_ROW0 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.169 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=2 COL1=T1C1_ROW1 COL2=T1C2_ROW1 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.169 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=3 COL1=T1C1_ROW2 COL2=T1C2_ROW2 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.169 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=4 COL1=T1C1_ROW3 COL2=T1C2_ROW3 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.169 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=5 COL1=T1C1_ROW4 COL2=T1C2_ROW4 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.170 D/DBINFO: TABLE1 ROW ID=6 COL1=T1C1_ROW5 COL2=T1C2_ROW5 COL3=0
2023-09-03 15:08:13.171 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=1 COL1=T2C1_ROW10 COL2=T2C2_ROW10
2023-09-03 15:08:13.171 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=2 COL1=T2C1_ROW12 COL2=T2C2_ROW12
2023-09-03 15:08:13.171 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=3 COL1=T2C1_ROW14 COL2=T2C2_ROW14
2023-09-03 15:08:13.171 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=4 COL1=T2C1_ROW16 COL2=T2C2_ROW16
2023-09-03 15:08:13.171 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=5 COL1=T2C1_ROW18 COL2=T2C2_ROW18
2023-09-03 15:08:13.172 D/DBINFO: TABLE2 ROW ID=6 COL1=T2C1_ROW20 COL2=T2C2_ROW20
```

- Database existed and was version 1 but has been changed by Room to version 2
- The data in Table1 has been retained (still the 6 rows)
- The new col3 in Table1 has been populated with the default value
- Table2 exists and has been populated.

**Stage 4*

The App is rerun without any changes so no Migration takes place, As expected the log contains `D/DBINFO: Database Existed when started = true Version before Room access = 2 Version after Room access = 2`. Table1 and Table show the same data.

**Stage 5**

The code is changed back as per Version 1 and the App is rerun. The log contains:

```
2023-09-03 15:18:57.541 D/DBINFO: Version of database (before Room Access) is 2 if 0 then database does not exist
2023-09-03 15:18:57.632 D/DBINFO: Database Existed when started = true Version before Room access = 2 Version after Room access = 1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.632 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e2e29ad
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out: 0 {
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out: 1 {
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    name=original_table1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.633 I/System.out:    tbl_name=original_table1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "original_table1" (`table1Id` INTEGER, `table1Col1` TEXT NOT NULL, `table1Col2` TEXT NOT NULL, table1Col3 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY(`table1Id`))
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out: 2 {
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    tbl_name=room_master_table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out: 3 {
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.634 I/System.out:    name=table2
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    tbl_name=table2
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE table2 (table2Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, table2Col1 TEXT NOT NULL, table2Col2 TEXT NOT NULL)
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out: 4 {
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    type=table
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    name=Table1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Table1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    rootpage=7
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `Table1` (`table1Id` INTEGER, `table1Col1` TEXT NOT NULL, `table1Col2` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`table1Id`))
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out: }
2023-09-03 15:18:57.635 I/System.out: <<<<<
2023-09-03 15:18:57.640 D/DBINFO: ID=1 COL1=T1C1_ROW0 COL2=T1C2_ROW0
2023-09-03 15:18:57.640 D/DBINFO: ID=2 COL1=T1C1_ROW1 COL2=T1C2_ROW1
2023-09-03 15:18:57.640 D/DBINFO: ID=3 COL1=T1C1_ROW2 COL2=T1C2_ROW2
2023-09-03 15:18:57.640 D/DBINFO: ID=4 COL1=T1C1_ROW3 COL2=T1C2_ROW3
2023-09-03 15:18:57.641 D/DBINFO: ID=5 COL1=T1C1_ROW4 COL2=T1C2_ROW4
2023-09-03 15:18:57.641 D/DBINFO: ID=6 COL1=T1C1_ROW5 COL2=T1C2_ROW5
```

- The database exists, it was version 2 and Room has changed it to version 1.
- The Schema shows:-

  - That the non-Room tables original_table1 and table2 (which is not now in the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation) have no adverse affect as far as running the App is concerned (waste storage could be an issue in some cases).

If **AppInspection** is used then this confirms the existence of these ***non-Room*** tables:-

[image]

And that the data still exists in these ***non-Room*** tables as per:-

[image]

- of course typically these ***non-Room*** tables would be dropped. However, they could be utilised if say Col3's data had to be retained (but that's out of scope, especially how (as how is outside of the scope of Room)).

Comment: This goldmine of infos has entirely to few upvotes